# Prevent re-render with every URI for React Router params

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Given the following route, if a URI query is added or changed (i.e. `?bar2=foo`) then `MySpecialComponent` will rerender even though it isn't set to capture these params:

```
<Route exact path="/foo/:bar" render={props => (<MySpecialComponent/>)}/>
```

This causes a massive amount of re-rendering when used throughout. How can the unwanted params be ignored? I.e. to not triggering a re-render until the bit we care about changes (`/foo/:bar`).

Answer (score 0):

I found using `render` on `route` along with passing the params myself to be the cleanest solution (to not pollute containers with router logic):

```
<Route exact path="/foo/:bar" render={props => (
  // Only pass needed props to avoid unnecessary re-render on ANY URI change
  <MySpecialComponent bar={props.match.params.bar}/>
)}/>
```